# MooTools More "new Date().parse()" yields wrong month in Chrome / WebKit

Tags: google-chrome, datetime, webkit, mootools, mootools-more

Consider this snippet using the latest **MooTools Core & More 1.5** ([view in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Lmwstav/)):

```
console.log(new Date().parse('2014-09-20 00:00:00'));
```

When I run this code, I *usually* get something along the lines of

```
Sat Sep 20 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)
```

However, when I use Chrome (38.0.2125.104 m) or a PyQt 4 WebKit window **and** use a **Russian time zone** (anything in Windows with an `RTZ` in its name), the date is **1 month in the future**:

```
Mon Oct 20 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Eastern Europe Daylight Time)
```

This apparently does *not* occur with Firefox or Internet Explorer, or apparently any non-Russian time zone.

Anybody know why ?

Comment: `Date.parse('2014-09-20 00:00:00+0300')` ? also, what string do you actually pass in, where are you (locally) at the time when you run it (CET?), do you get the same errors via `moment.js` - http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/ - you may need to set tz offset http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/timezone-offset/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is apparently caused by Chrome bugs [417640](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=417640) and [420269](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=420269).

Dates between `2014-01-01 00:00:00` (inclusive) and `2014-01-01 01:00:00` (exclusive) simply do not exist as such, they resolve to `2013-12-31 23:00:00` - `2013-12-31 23:59:59` instead.

You can reproduce this with an RTZ:

```
var d = new Date();

d.setHours(0);
d.setMinutes(0);
d.setSeconds(0);
d.setYear(2014);
d.setDate(1);

d.setMonth(0);
console.log(d.getMonth()); // Yields 11 rather than 0
```

This is because `Date.parse('2014-01-01 00:00:00')` yields `2013-12-31` in the date part due to time zone issues.

This bug affects other dates as well because of the way MooTools' `Date` extensions work (initializing dates with `year-01-01 00:00:00` and then subsequently setting extracted values, e.g. `12:34:56 Sep 25, 2014` would be derived like this:

```
2014-01-01 00:00:00 // Initialization
2013-12-31 23:00:00 // Resolved date with RTZ
2014-12-31 23:00:00 // Year
2014-09-31 23:00:00 // Month
2014-10-01 23:00:00 // Resolved date with overflow
2014-10-25 23:00:00 // Day of month
2014-10-25 12:34:56 // Time
```